# How to specify, with flex, which parts will expand when resizing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How I can control which divs will grow/shrink during resizing.
To be more specify, I have:

- container with fixed max width and height
- Header with fix height
- content, which contain 3 divs

  - box-1 - need to be resizable. This box need to be divided into two columns on that way that first I want to fill first column and if there is need to move to second one
  - box-2 same as box-1
  - box-3 with fixed size
- footer with fix height

Also I want that these 3 box in content div always stretch in window, independent of content

This is something that I tried, but obviously I make something wrong.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="box-1">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </div>

            <div class="box-2">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, dignissimos.
            </div>

            <div class="box-3">
                <ul>
                    <li>Item1</li>
                    <li>Item2</li>
                    <li>Item3</li>
                    <li>Item4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="footer"><h3>Footer</h3></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 900px;
    max-height: 800px;
}

.header{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.footer{
    height: 20px;
    background-color: tomato;
}

.box-1{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 50%;
    column-count: 1;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.box-2{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    column-count: 1;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.box-3{
    display: flex;
    background-color: plum;
    justify-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommand to use [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/). You will be able to resize containers verry easily